# define minimum length column in xsd

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd-validation

i am trying to generate an xsd based on a database created in vs.net 2008. How can i specify the minimum length for a column in my xsd? i want to be able to do this in vs.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
   <xsd:minLength value='0'/>
   <xsd:maxLength value='50'/>
  </xsd:restriction>
```

Comment: can i specify this somewhere in vs.net 2008

Comment: In VS 2008, Click on the Column in the XSD Designer, and press F4, set the MaxLength in the property to whatever you want.

Comment: For some reason the MinLength is not allowed on the DataColumn, you can try setting the XML element by dragging the XSD in the notepad, not sure if it works even after that, but you can give a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use restrictions:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="100"/>
</xs:restriction>
```